# nginx connect() to ip:80 failed (99: Address not available)

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I am using openresty for our proxy services on amazon linux2. Upon high load, we started to see below errors in specific environment only

```
[crit] 10#10: *451875 connect() to 100.xx.xx.xxx:80 failed (99: Address not available)
```

And there are many 502 errors returned from the proxy layer itself. (there was no error/failure log found at the upstream).

I already have the ulimit increased and also based on other [similar stackoverflow issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144396/nginx-proxy-connect-to-ip80-failed-99-cannot-assign-requested-address) increased the local port range(ephemeral port). But still facing the issue.
(This is running on k8s 1.20). Could anyone please help?

Comment: using `openresty:1.13.6.2-alpine-fat`

Comment: The answer mentioned here fixed this problem for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66421816/14951352